# How to produce a table with column and row headers included?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have searched and have not found a solution.

```
n = Table[i^2 + j*3, {i, 3}, {j, 7}] // TableForm
Export["stuck.xls", n]
```

> ```
> 4  7  10  13  16  19  22
> 7  10 13  16  19  22  25
> 12 15 18  21  24  27  30
> ```

What I want is to have the cell columns and rows give me exactly what `i` and `j` were, like this:

```
    j   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
i                               
1       4   7   10  13  16  19  22
2       7   10  13  16  19  22  25
3       12  15  18  21  24  27  30
```

From this I can see that the result of `i=3` and `j=7` is 30.

Can anyone help with this task?

Comment: this did not paste like I expected.  The columns should have been 7 wide (as shown) but the rows should have been 3 deep.  The place where you see a number 2 should have been the start of a new row and where the number 3 shows should have been the start of the third row . . . .sorry for the confussion

Comment: I fixed your post for you. Welcome to the site. Please have a look at the [faq], and you may also want to see the revised source code of your question that produced this formatting.

Comment: Hi Oleksandr,That was a speedy reply . . .thank you much

Comment: sorry, hit return too soon . . .where exactly can i see the "revised code" you referenced . . .thx again

Comment: Click on the "edited <> ago" text to see that: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/71378/revisions).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I looked through the faq before posting (maybe poorly ;-) i could not find an example where, in my case, the variable values of i and j were actually placed as header and row labels.  I am actually working on creating arrays of option theoretical values across various stock price and volatility combinations.  What I can't see is what exact stock price and volatility combination yields the particular call price in each cell.

Comment: And thank you for the kind welcome Lou :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pad `n` with required column and row headers before exporting to Excel:

```
padF = With[{d = Dimensions[#], ap = ArrayPad[#, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, ""]}, 
    Transpose@Prepend[Transpose[Join[{Prepend[Range@d[[2]], "j"]}, ap]], 
                      Join[{"", "i"}, Range@d[[1]]]]] &;

n = Table[i^2 + j*3, {i, 3}, {j, 7}];
nn = padF@n;
Export["stuck2.xlsx", nn]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `TableHeadings` option of `TableForm`.

```
table = Table[i^2 + j*3, {i, 1, 3, .5}, {j, 1, 7, .5}];
rowHeaders = Range[1, 3, .5];
columnHeaders = Range[1, 7, .5];
{rowVar, columnVar} = {"i", "j"};

TableForm[table, TableHeadings -> {rowHeaders, columnHeaders}]
```

If you want to show the row and column variable names then you have to pad the data with empty strings to make room for the extra labels.

```
TableForm[
  ArrayPad[table, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, ""],
  TableHeadings -> {{rowVar}~Join~rowHeaders,
                    {columnVar}~Join~columnHeaders}
]
```

Note: Data should be left as data (`Table` or `List`); separate from presentation (`TableForm`). That way you can choose to display it as a `TableForm`, `MatrixForm`, or easily work with the data the later on. In particular

```
(* Bad practice *)
n = Table[i^2 + j*3, {i, 3}, {j, 7}] // TableForm;
(* Fail *)
TableForm[n, TableHeadings -> {Range@3, Range@7}]
```

Edit: There used to be an answer by @kguler which addresses exporting the headers to Excel by prepending the headers to the data. This uses the same method, perhaps in a more easily readable format.

```
formatTable[table_, {rowHeaders_, columnHeaders_}, {rowVar_, columnVar_}] :=
  table //
  ArrayPad[#, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, ""] & //
  Prepend[#, {columnVar}~Join~columnHeaders] & //
  Transpose // 
  Prepend[#, {"", rowVar}~Join~rowHeaders] & //
  Transpose;

Export["stuck.xls", formatTable[table, {rowHeaders, columnHeaders}, {rowVar, columnVar}]]
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, This works as long as my increments are integers.  But what about when my formula looks like this  n = Table[i^2 + j*3, {i, 1, 3, .1}, {j, 1, 7, .1}];

Comment: `TableHeadings->{Range[1,3,.1],Range[1,7,.1]}`

Comment: Bingo, thank you very much and thank you as well kguler !

Comment: Ok, sorry to bring this thread up again, i got the table to contain headers in Mathematica just fine but when I export to excel they were missing once again :-(  I am new to all of this so i apologize for what are probably painfully mundane questions.  Thanks in advance for the help all

Comment: i realize now that i did not mention the word "excel" in the question, i will be more clear in the future all